# the loss didn't drop in tf with keras cifar10 datesets

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I create a vgg like model in tensorflow and use cifar10 in keras to train it, but the loss didn't drop, can u find what's the problem?

cifar10 datesets

```py
from keras.datasets import cifar100, cifar10
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


def load_cifar(num_class=100):
    if num_class == 100:
        nb_classes = 100
        (trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = cifar100.load_data()
    else:
        nb_classes = 10
        (trainX, trainY), (testX, testY) = cifar10.load_data()

    trainX = trainX.astype('float32')
    testX = testX.astype('float32')

    trainX /= 255.
    testX /= 255.

    Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(trainY, nb_classes)
    Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(testY, nb_classes)

    generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=15,
                                   width_shift_range=5. / 32,
                                   height_shift_range=5. / 32,
                                   horizontal_flip=True if num_class ==10 else False)

    generator.fit(trainX, seed=0)
    return trainX, Y_train, testX, Y_test, generator
```

model and train

```py
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../'))
print(sys.path)
import tensorflow as tf
from Input import cifar

BatchSize = 2

def gen_gen(batch_size=BatchSize):
    trainX, Y_train, testX, Y_test, generator = cifar.load_cifar(10)
    gen = generator.flow(trainX, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size)
    return gen


class vgg16TF():
    def __init__(self, ih=32, iw=32, batch_size=BatchSize):
        self.ih = ih
        self.iw = iw
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def unit(self, x, conv_nums, filters, name=None):
        for i in range(1, conv_nums+1):
            x = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=x, filters=filters, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same',
                                 use_bias=True, activation=tf.nn.relu, name=name+'_conv'+str(i))
        x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(x, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), name=name+'_pool')
        return x

    def net(self):
        input_x = tf.placeholder(shape=(self.batch_size, self.ih, self.iw, 3), dtype=tf.float32)
        x = self.unit(input_x, 2, 64, name='blook1')
        x = self.unit(x, 2, 64, name='blook2')
        # x = self.unit(x, 3, 256, name='blook3')
        # x = self.unit(x, 3, 512, name='blook4')
        # x = self.unit(x, 3, 512, name='blook5')
        x = tf.layers.flatten(x, name='flatten')
        x = tf.layers.dense(x, 384, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc1', use_bias=True)
        x = tf.layers.dense(x, 192, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='fc2', use_bias=True)
        y = tf.layers.dense(x, 10, name='prediction', use_bias=True)
        print(y)
        return input_x, y

    def loss(self, labels, logits):
        labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int64)
        cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            labels=tf.arg_max(labels,1), logits=logits
        )
        cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entropy_mean)
        return tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'))


    def train(self):
        input_x, y_ = self.net()
        input_y = tf.placeholder(shape=(self.batch_size, 10), dtype=tf.float64)
        loss = self.loss(input_y, y_)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss=loss)
        # correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.arg_max(y_, 1), tf.arg_max(input_y, 1))
        # accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
            gen = gen_gen()
            for i in range(10000):
                train_x, train_y = gen.next()
                # print(train_x.shape)
                loss_val, _ = sess.run([loss, optimizer], feed_dict={input_x: train_x, input_y: train_y})
                if i % 10 == 0:
                    print(loss_val)
```

some loss of train step:
2.2985106
2.2944324
2.3120923
2.306837
2.304546
2.2818785
2.3069105
2.3087378
2.3094501
2.2966876
2.3119392
2.2941442
2.2990022
2.2830834
2.3137615

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious errors in the code, but I can share my experience that the Adam optimizer does not always work well with VGG-like networks due to the large number of parameters, and the symptom is that the loss does not decrease. In that case you should use plain SGD with an appropriate learning rate and a schedule.